# For loop question: my code works fine but the software won't count it as correct

Tags: python

Question:

Prompt the user to enter a number 50 and 100 inclusive of both. Store this in a variable called num, convert this input to an integer.

Print out all the numbers between that number and 200, inclusive.

For each even number, print the exact string: ‘Fizz’. Check whether num is even using the expression n % 2 == 0. Put this in an if-statement.

For each odd number, print the extra string: ‘Buzz’. Put this in an else-statement.

**My code output seems fine, but the software won't count it as correct somehow: see below**

```
num = int(input('enter a number 50 and 100 inclusive of both: '))

for i in range(num, 201):
    print(i)
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print('Fizz')
    else:
        print('Buzz')
```

when enter the number 100:

enter a number 50 and 100 inclusive of both: 100

100
Fizz

101
Buzz

102
Fizz

103
Buzz

.....

199
Buzz

200
Fizz

No idea why my code is marked wrong......please help

Comment: You are not handling the case where the user enters a number less than 50 or greater than 200.

Comment: Which software are you talking about? What is the accepted result format in that software?

Comment: i.e ```if num < 50 or num >200 return```

Comment: @SwaroopDeval probably hackerrank or leetcode type stuff.

Comment: The sample output you give here doesn't match your code, which doesn't put the strings on the same lines as the numbers.

Comment: Maybe just lose the prompt message in the `input()` and change the line to `num = int(input())` as, if you're submitting it to a website line hackerrank, it is required that you do not print any thing but the final ouput

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are not checking weather the number is inbetween 50 and 100, using the if statement below should handle that.

```
num = int(input('enter a number 50 and 100 inclusive of both: '))
if num >= 50 and num <= 100:
    for i in range(num, 201):
        print(i)
        if i % 2 == 0:
              print('Fizz')
        else:
              print('Buzz')
```

Comment: doesn't work, the software still gives an error, I will do more digging on it but thanks for the feedback nevertheless!